# Tikz externalize error when using tikzducks

Tags: tikz-external, tikzducks

I am using `tikzducks` for my footers, simply because I think they are brilliant. Because my document contains lots of other tikzpictures, I want to make use of `\tikzexternalize`. This works perfectly fine if I do not use the `tikzducks`. With the `tikzducks`, the `tikzexternalize` fails when generating the final duck. A simple solution would be to disable the `tikzducks`. But yeah... a report without a duck, that's a bridge too far. So could anyone help me out?

My MWE (`document.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}                             %5 generate lorum ipsum text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                           %% page headers and footers
\usepackage{tikzducks}                          %% ducks with tikz

\pagestyle{fancy}                               %% set page style
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}           %% header line width
\fancyfoot[C]{\shuffleducks\tikz[scale=0.35]{\duck[signpost={\footnotesize\thepage},\randomhead]}}

\usetikzlibrary{external}                       %% Create pdf figures from TikZ. Use PDFTeXify ...
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]                  %% ... with --tex-option=--shell-escape switch.

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I use the following code for compilation:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "document".tex
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/document-figure1" "\def\tikzexternal
realjob{document}\input{document}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tik
z/document-figure1' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that
 you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.
 Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the com
mand simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/document-figure1.log'.
 If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

This is what the log file says:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image 
was EMPTY. I tried to externalize 'tikz/document-figure1', but it seems there i
s no such image in the document!?  
You are currently using 'mode=convert with system call'. This problem can ha
ppen if the image (or one of the images preceeding it) was declared inside of a
\label{} (i.e. in the .aux file): 'convert with system call' has no access to 
the main aux file.
Possible solutions in this case:
(a) Try using 'mode=list and make',
(b) Issue the externalization command 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/document-figure1" "\def\tikzexternalreal
job{document}\input{document}"' *manually* (also check the preceeding externali
zed images, perhaps the file name sequence is not correct).
Repeat: the resulting image was EMPTY, your attention is required .
```

Comment: Why don't you just disable externalisation before the last duck? Also, as the message you posted says: the details are in the file the message refers you to and which you can read, but we can't.

Comment: That sounds as a solution. How can I do that? I added the error message in the log file (thanks for suggesting this)

Comment: `\tikzexternaldisable` is sometimes enough, but sometimes I find I need `\tikzset{external/export=false}`, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem comes from tikzducks? Or may it be related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211861/121799)? (I'm just guessing, and the fix proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211872/121799) does not solve the problem.)

Comment: It is not related to tikzducks, you get the same problem with an arbitrary \tikz picture in the footer.

Comment: I was about to say that :). I posted my workaround as a possible answer (but if you've a better answer, let me know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log file says:

> This problem can happen if the image (or one of the images preceeding it) was declared inside of a \label{} (i.e. in the .aux file)...

Could it be that the footer at the last page is inside a `label{}`? Because the error only appears at the last page. Since one can refer to the last page using the reference key `LastPage`, I think this might be the case.

**Edit**: based on a comment below, this is not the case. Nevertheless, we "are in the middle of the output routine and one should not do complicated things like externalization there".

Anyway, since the `tikzducks` do not have a big influence on the compilation of the document, it is not very important to "tikzexternalize" the ducks. I found the following workaround for the footer (based on the comment of cfr):

```
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \tikzset{external/export=false}
    \shuffleducks\tikz[scale=0.35]{\duck[signpost={\footnotesize\thepage},\randomhead]}
}
```

In this way, all tikzpictures are externalized, except for the tikzducks in the footer.

Comment: You are not inside a label. But you are in the middle of the output routine and one should do complicated things like externalization there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the clarification. So then this solution makes sense (i.e., all tikzpictures are externalized except for the tikzpictures in the footer)?

Comment: Yes. And I naturally meant one should *not* do complicated things there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. I understood the *not* :)